# C++ Result of derefencing "this" keyword

Tags: c++, this, dereference

I'm currently learning C++ by studying the book C++ Primer 5th Edition. I'm at the part of the book where classes are being introduced in-depth and the book just introduced the "this" keyword.

```
Sales_data& Sales_data::combine(const Sales_data &rhs){
    units_sold += rhs.units_sold;
    revenue += rhs.revenue;
    return *this;
}
```

I'm having trouble understanding the return type for this member function.

The function head states that the function will return a reference to a Sales_data object. The book states that the type of **this** is a const pointer. The return statement derefences this which would produce a Sales_data object, and NOT a reference to a Sales_data object.

My question is: wouldn't the code segement above produce a compile time error because the function expects a reference to Sales_data to be returned but instead it simply gets a Sales_data object.

Comment: What do you pass in as parameter? An object? Why don't you get a compiler error because you pass an object and not a reference?

Comment: In terms of expressions, there is no difference between "a Sales_data object" and "a reference to a Sales_data object"

Answer (score 1):

The code *does* get a reference to a Sales_data object.  It just happens to be the very same object whose combine function was called.

The point of returning a reference to this is to allow you to *chain* calls.  So if Sales_data had other member functions named foo() and bar() you could do this

```
Sales_data sd1
Sales_data sd2;
sd1.combine(sd2).foo().bar();
```

If the book states that 'this' is a const pointer its wrong.  The only way that 'this' would be a const pointer in that function would be if the function itself were declared const.

Comment: "If the book states that this is a const pointer its wrong." Its a constant pointer to a non-constant object, I think that's what the book means.

Comment: Fair enough.  Then the confusion here apparently lies in the difference between a const pointer (meaning you can't make it point to some other object) vs a pointer to a const object (meaning that whatever object it points to you cannot change.)

Comment: @tkausl In fact the type of `this` is not even a const pointer to a non-const object. It is just a prvalue, so it can't be assigned to even though it's not const.

Comment: Interesting, so if 'this' is a prvalue then how come the function head declares combine to return a reference to Sales_data and not just a Sales_data object.

Comment: @L.Key the difference is do you want a different object or the same one?  If you want the person who called combine() to get back a *different* object, you return a Sales_data.  In that case a copy will be made.  However if you want the person who called combine() to get back the *exact same* object, you return a Sales_data&.  In that case, no function will be called and no copy will be made.

Comment: Ahhhh now I understand it, clearly we want to return the existing object and not a copy of it and that is why function head states that it will return a reference. I should definetly brush up on my understanding of references before I continue any furhter.

Just want to say thank you to everybody who helped. My first time using stackoverflow and I was not expecting to get so much help and so quickly! You guys are the best!

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a non-mutable pointer of type `Sales_data`, not a `const` pointer in the sense of `int* const`.

Specifically, since your function is non-const, it's a temporary (= prvalue) of type `Sales_data*`, and since temporaries of primitive types, like pointers, cannot be modified, you cannot make that `this` points to anything else.

It is strictly bound to the object where you are, and making it a temporary is what allows it to be treated as a constant pointer and protect the bounding restrictions, while allowing it to return a non-const reference while dereferencing it.

However, if your function where `const`, like in:

```
Sales_data& Sales_data::foo(const Sales_data &rhs) const;
```

Then `this` is a prvalue of type `const Sales_data*`; a temporary pointer to constant object (because you have "const"ified the object inside that function) but not a `const` pointer (non-modifiable because its a temporary, but not `const`-qualified). So, `*this` has type `const Sales_data&` and you will get a compiler error if you return `*this` inside that function. You must then change the function signature to:

```
const Sales_data& Sales_data::foo(const Sales_data &rhs) const;
```

Comment: "*this is a non-mutable pointer of type ... " Is the * before the "this" a typo or am I misunderstanding something. Thanks.

Comment: constant pointer and a pointer to a constant value are different things.
this is synonymous to a reference: type * const ptr;
while pointer to a constant value is: const type * ptr;

Comment: @noop yes I know, have I said something wrong in the question? I have re-readed and don't see it.

Comment: @MFisherKDX it was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: @Peregring-lk initial version was looking like it meant something different.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your confusion comes from a feature of the C++ compiler (which comes from the C++ standard). These two function signatures mean different things:

`Sales_data& Sales_data::combine(const Sales_data &rhs)`

`Sales_data Sales_data::combine(const Sales_data &rhs)`

The first one means that the function is going to return a reference of the Sales_data object, and the second one returns a copy of it. The compiler is smart enough to figure out what to do from the function signature rather than from the `return *this;` statement, which is the same in both cases.

Comment: You're definitely right about the effect, but I wouldn't call that a "quirk of the compiler"  It's a core part of the language.  Understanding it is key to understanding C++

Answer (score 0):

Not understanding what C++ reference is is a common pitfall among beginner C++ programmers. Reference is a constant pointer in disguise, that is automatically dereferenced. It **is** a pointer but is used as a value, with * invisibly added before the identifier every time you use it *after* creating it. You always create reference by assigning something to it, and when you do it **&** is invisibly added to the entity being assigned, taking its address. Therefore assigning ***this** actually means **&*this**, where & negates *, and the reference simply gets the value of pointer **this**.

When used within a method of Sales_data class, **this** is a pointer to an object of **Sales_data** type.
Return type of this method is a reference, which, as I already explained is essentially also a pointer to the same type as this, but used with a different syntax. returning ***this** just converts between syntax of a pointer and the syntax of a reference while actually doing **nothing**.

Basically, these two cases generate exactly the same code but look different.

```
Sales_data& Sales_data::combine(const Sales_data &rhs){
    // ...
    return *this;
}
// ...
{
    Sales_data a, b, c, d;
    a.combine(b).combine(c).combine(d);
}


Sales_data* Sales_data::combine(const Sales_data &rhs){
    // ...
    return this;
}
// ...
{
    Sales_data a, b, c, d;
    (*(*a.combine(b)).combine(c)).combine(d);
    // Or, also exactly the same code:
    a.combine(b)->combine(c)->combine(d);
}
```

Unability to distinguish between reference and value when reading an isolated piece of code is one of the many C++ "features" that give it well deserved reputation of a language designed for shooting your legs off.
In order to retain your sanity longer you should prefer const references and only use non-const references for a few cases such as this idiom.